# Best method to compare indexes

Tags: correlation, method-comparison

I have implemented three different estimates to measure the same character, and I would like to statistically compare them (to see if they indeed measure the exact same signal, or if they give different pieces of information).
How can I do that?

Correlation test always find a significant correlation, but since the estimates measure the same thing...

You can take a look at the dataset [here](http://txt.do/566lr)

Comment: Welcome to CV. It would seem that there are several ways to approach this problem. If it's possible to treat the "character" being measured as a latent, underlying or hidden dimension, then PCA would describe their relationships. Related to PCA, a measurement error model rooted in structural equation modeling would provide a different approach. By "fixing" one of the metrics, this method would allow you to compare how different (erroneous) the other two metrics are. Another option would be to use some sort of distance function, e.g., Kullback-Leibler divergence, for comparison.

Comment: Search the site for discussions of concordance correlation. Pearson correlation is fallacious here. To see this consider $y = bx$ where $b$ is positive and arbitrarily large. Pearson correlation between $y$ and $x$ is naturally perfect at $+1$ but $y$ and $x$ do not agree.

Comment: As @DJohnson rightly points out, a full-blown treatment of this problem would point towards a measurement error model. It's often, however, helpful at least to start very simply with exploratory and descriptive analysis.

Comment: @NickCox The descriptive work is already done ^^ I am looking for a deeper analysis of the problem.

Comment: @DJohnson I am not sure the character can be treated as a underlying dimension.
PCA gives a first eigenvalue of only 15%...

But the measurement error model with a fixed metric seems perfectly adequate. One of my estimates would be a perfect reference metric, since it is much less subject to biases than the others.

What would be the procedure to do this on R?

Comment: There are probably several R modules for SEM. Here's one method ... http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/sem/SEM-paper.pdf

Comment: @NickCox My metrics measure a state of preservation.
They assess it throughout different methods, but in the end, a poorly preserved specimen cannot have high values for either of the metrics (nor can a well preserved have low values).

Comment: A first eigenvalue of 15% makes no sense; that can't happen without the second eigenvalue being at least 42.5%, which is a contradiction. Some misconception there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the data have been posted some simple analyses help make the situation clearer.

Let's show (half of) a scatter plot matrix.

[image]

There is a lot of scatter. A and B are clearly most similar; C is largely dissimilar to B but shows more relation to A. There aren't problems with extraordinary outliers or massive curvature.

Concordance correlations quantify this without adding insight:

```
A B  0.704 
B C  0.363 
A C  0.638
```

Concordance correlations measure agreement, not linearity, and are 1 if and only if two variables have identical values.

The principal component analysis I would base on a covariance matrix, as it seems that the units of measurement are identical. These results (from Stata) don't match those in the OP's comments:

```
. pca A B C, cov

Principal components/covariance                   Number of obs    =        70
                                                  Number of comp.  =         3
                                                  Trace            =  .1942012
    Rotation: (unrotated = principal)             Rho              =    1.0000

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Component |   Eigenvalue   Difference         Proportion   Cumulative
    -------------+------------------------------------------------------------
           Comp1 |      .153565      .123528             0.7908       0.7908
           Comp2 |     .0300363     .0194362             0.1547       0.9454
           Comp3 |     .0106001            .             0.0546       1.0000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

Principal components (eigenvectors) 

    ----------------------------------------------------------
        Variable |    Comp1     Comp2     Comp3 | Unexplained 
    -------------+------------------------------+-------------
               A |   0.6037    0.1114   -0.7894 |           0 
               B |   0.4836    0.7360    0.4738 |           0 
               C |   0.6337   -0.6678    0.3904 |           0 
    ----------------------------------------------------------
```

So, with a covariance matrix input, PCA shows PC1 with 79% of the total. 
(Using a correlation matrix produces the same rounded result of 79% for the first PC; from the graphs it is evident that the variances of the variables are similar.)

I wouldn't personally mush together A, B and C and take PC 1 as the best measure of a latent variable. Either C is the poorest measure and should be discarded and A and B combined; or there might be quite independent grounds for thinking that C is the best method, in which case it should be used. Consider three witnesses in court: two liars might agree with each other and disagree with one honest person. The majority need not be correct. Conversely, on a consensus or coherence criterion C looks poorest.

EDIT: Here is a quantile plot, which underlines what the scatter plots do show, but less clearly, which is that C is typically smallest.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the analysis!
What I don't really understand though, is why C appears to be the poorest measure of the three.
And how to intrepret the values of Lin's concordance ?

Comment: I know nothing about A, B. C that you haven't told me! It's at most a coherence argument, on all fours with "She said that, but no one else who was there agrees".  More prosaically put, we distrust a signal if there is no independent evidence to the same effect. Lin's concordance: start with http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/does-the-concordance-correlation-coefficient-make-linearity-or-monotone-assumpti

Comment: It happens that C is precisely less prone to biases than the two others.

Comment: Interesting. I've added a quantile plot to the answer, which brings home that the distributions are indeed dissimilar.

Comment: Nick Cox's analysis is interesting as well as useful but, to KermittDuss' comment above, he is seeking deeper insights. An SEM measurement error model might provide that insight.

Comment: @DJohnson Could you suggest an SEM or post an analysis? That would be interesting too.

Comment: @nickcox  I had a feeling you would ask for that! Here's a link to some lecture notes on SEM, how it relates to CFA (confirmatory factor analysis), path analysis and measurement error. Good discussion of ME beginning on p. 6. And beginning on p. 19 is a comparison of SEM and multiple regression. http://www.columbia.edu/~mmw2177/LVcourse/sem_slides1.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but I really wasn't asking for a reading list: I was asking for a claim to be substantiated. You have the data now and context in the question and further comments. (The bounds of $[0,1]$ would have to be respected by any serious model.)

Comment: @NickCox  By describing my comment as a *claim* and not a *suggestion* you've escalated its significance. Normally, I enjoy helping OPs out with analytics and have done so on more than a few recent occasions. In this case, however, I will have to defer. I've "learned" several versions of SEM software over the years via workshops of one kind or another but, use it or lose it. At this point, it's been years since I've done anything with SEMs. And, at this point in time, I'm neither sufficiently interested in nor motivated by this problem to want to attempt to pick SEM back up.

Comment: @DJohnson SEMs were mentioned four times previously by you, so I thought you were being shy in holding back on a precise analysis. But  without substantiation, the suggestion [NB: agreed that this is the better word] that SEMs would go deeper reduces to an interesting speculation. My analysis is that, given comments from the OP's subject-matter knowledge, the relatively clear patterns in the data point to C as the method of choice. I would be fascinated if a tailored SEM added to or contradicted that.

Comment: @DJohnson I agree with NickCox in that the concordance/PCA/plot analysis is sufficient to compare the mehods. Results are pretty clear, there is no need to complicate the matter, especially if it is not worth it.

Comment: Only one other little question (one more...) : what would be a way to quantify the 'distortion' between C (the "reliable" metric) and the two others? I still don't really get why, with a good agreement between A&C and A&B, there is only a poor between B&C.
Could implementation issues operate here?
C and A have a common core in their implementation, while A and B are closer in what they measure.
From a logical point of view, I do not understand the absence of agreement between B and C, but from a methodological point of view, they are the two most distant.
Enough to account for the results?

Comment: I would just look at the differences, e.g. A $-$ C.  I think you're right to factor in your subject-matter knowledge of the methods but that's precisely where we can't add usefully.

Comment: For the record, I did not say, and do not assert, that the descriptive analysis is entirely sufficient here. As I said, "a full-blown treatment of this problem would point towards a measurement error model. It's often, however, helpful at least to start very simply with exploratory and descriptive analysis". We haven't seen what a model could add here but no-one should presume without trying that we would not learn more. I don't use these models either, but that's incidental.